# Non maximized window weird browse, tags, Stack Apps

Tags: bug, tags, design, stackapps, responsive-design

Tags stack weirdly on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com):

[image]

Comment: reproduced on Chrome / Win 10.

Comment: Also on FF 69.0 reproduced

Comment: Repro on FF 68 and Chrome 76 on Mac 10.14.6

Comment: Mine was Opera, but glad that's unimportant detail.

Comment: [Related fix needed](https://stackapps.com/a/8112/7653). Also, [this "status-planned" change](https://stackapps.com/a/8113/7653).  The Stack Apps home pages are not making a good impression on new users.

Comment: @AwesomePoodles perhaps ping someone on that "status-planned" as that is almost a year old now.

Comment: @Luuklag, there are ["status-planned" posts much, much older than that](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackapps/query/1103467/smart-search-for-posts-by-tags-combinations-with-optional-date-and-sort-parame?fromDate=2005-01-01&Tag1=status-planned&Tag2=NA&Tag3=NA&Tag4=NA&sortOrder=ASC).  The hope is that if anyone addresses this bug, they also take those related bugs into account.